# Drag and drop image file from explorer to application

Tags: passwords

I'm trying to drag an image file from explorer into my wpf image control. My current code is

```
private void Image_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    string fpath = (string)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat); 
    BitmapImage tmpImage = new BitmapImage((new Uri(fpath))); 
    testImg.Source = tmpImage;
}
```

Which is currently giving me NullReferenceException error when I drop the file on the control.

Update:

Using Patrick's suggestion, by changing the code to this

```
private void Image_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    object data = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);

    foreach (string str in (string[])data)
    {
        BitmapImage tmpImage = new BitmapImage((new Uri(str)));
        testImg.Source = tmpImage;
    }
}
```

The image correctly update the source. Will probably need to add code for handling multiple images selection drop.

Comment: Did you paste something over the question title by mistake?

Comment: Oops, my add-on auto fill the name when I edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [`DataFormats.FileDrop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dataformats.filedrop%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It will give a list of file names in the `GetData`. This is a working example from my own app:

```
object data = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);

if (data is string[])
{
    string[] files = (string[])data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get a file as a string, so I imagine it's your `e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat)` line that is throwing. If you're dropping a bitmap onto your control then you can treat it as such. Try this.

```
private void Image_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    BitmapImage tmpImage = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
    testImg.Source = tmpImage;
}
```

Although I recommend you put in code to ensure you are checking the type of what has been dragged onto your control before assuming it is a bitmap.

Comment: That code doesn't give me an error but when dropping the file, the image seemingly disappeared since I can no longer drop on that section. Thanks for the recommendation, I do have code to check the file but removed for simplicity.